# How do you calculate integers overflow?

Tags: math, arithmetic-expressions

I try to calculate, based on given parameters, integer overflow.
for example, if I have an integer than is <= 200, but when I insert it to an unsigned int, it will be > 200. What is the actual arithmetic process for that?

Comment: Ok. that wasnt as difficult as expected. Just add 2^32 to the number.

Answer (score 2):

Operations on fixed size integers are usually made modulo 2<sup>m</sup>, where m is the number of bits (nowadays usually 32 or 64).

This means that a multiple of 2<sup>m</sup> is added or subtracted from the result to keep it in the range for the type, be it unsigned (0, 2<sup>m</sup>-1) or signed (-2<sup>m-1</sup>,  2<sup>m-1</sup>-1).

You might be interested in the [Mathematical foundations of computer integers](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/mathematical-foundations-of-computer-integers/).